# How to check member role?

Tags: python, discord.py, roles, member

How I can get a member role, for use it in match/case purposes

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    person_role = ? ? ?
    match person_role:
        case "User 1":
            pass
        case "User 2":
            pass
        case _:
            pass
```

From users roles depend what channel name set when new voice channel will be create.

Comment: It's hard to guess what you're trying to do. Please elaborate your question more and take a look at [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you're trying to only allow one role to use your command try: `@commands.has_role('somerole')`

Comment: I trying to define the role of the user who enters the channel, for switching between different logic of future channel name setting.

Comment: Still not sure what exactly you want to accomplish here. Do you want to get 1 specific role from a user? If so use `member.roles` and search through that list to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to get the roles of a member use `member.roles` which will return a list of type `discord.Role`. To find a certain role in that list, first get the role using either the name:

```py
role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="FunRole")
```

or the ID:

```py
role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=41153483483138)
```

Then see if the role is in the members list of roles:

```py
if role in member.roles:
    print("They have this role.")
```